# Where is information for all publicly available platform resources?

Tags: android

I've found a few 3rd party sites that have, for example, the drawables listed. However, I cannot find a document on the Android SDK site that gives an overview of the platform resources available for developers, including shapes, styles, and such. It would be nice to see it all laid out in one place and to see which API levels they are available from. Is there a document, either on the SDK site or provided by someone else, that gives an overview of all platform resources?

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html

Comment: Thank you. Looking at this it appears there are no publicly available platform shapes via XML. The shape objects are located in `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.*`. Is there any way to references from XML?

Comment: It is different thing. android.R.* is standart resource (menu, style, layout etc). But android.graphics.drawable.shapes.* is one of this package's class.

You can create custom shapes in xml file ([http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape]) and use them in your layout

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a document, either on the SDK site or provided by someone else, that gives an overview of all platform resources?

They are on your development machine, wherever you have your SDK installed. Go into `platforms/.../data/res` and they are all there (where `...` is some Android version).

Part of the reason for distributing them this way is that device manufacturers can and do change some of these resources on their devices, mostly drawables and strings. Most times, you are better served copying drawables from the SDK into your project, so that you maintain internal consistency within your application.