# Android;Body of ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog, findviewbyid

I **saw** this source as layout of `AlertDialog` in res\layout folder of Android SDK:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/body"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <ProgressBar android:id="@android:id/progress"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="10000"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dip" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried to find TextView that it's id is "message" like this:

```
TextView tvMessage = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
```

It works fine.Then I tried to find LinearLayout that it's id is "body" like this:

```
LinearLayout body = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.body);
```

But eclipse show this error:

```
body cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

This is snippet code:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(WriteOpinionActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("some text");
dialog.show();
TextView tvMessage = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
LinearLayout body = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.body);
```

Why this error occurs and how I can reach "body"?

Comment: Has it occurred on some particular device? Also, are You sure if device Android version corresponds to res\layout API level folder?

Comment: @sandrstar This is compile error and not exception,so before trying it on any device.Also `res\layout API level folder` and my `Project Build Target` are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, not all resources are accessible to You from platforms `res` folder.

E.g. I'm able to find `@+id/message` in `global_actions_item.xml, usb_storage_activity.xml, alert_dialog_holo.xml, js_prompt.xml, progress_dialog_holo.xml, progress_dialog.xml, alert_dialog.xml` (for API 17), and so, there's no warranty that You get `id` which defined in `progress_dialog.xml` (it can be defined in another file and just because of the same name You is able to find it in progress dialog).

Actually, public resources are defined [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html), however, it looks quite outdated, so some resources might be missed. Checkout these questions about lists of all accessible resources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487829/where-is-information-for-all-publicly-available-platform-resources) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673629/how-can-i-access-all-drawables-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```
TextView tvMessage = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);  
LinearLayout body = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.body);
```

You weren't actually using `android.R.id.message` in the first place. `@+id/message` means you are creating a new `id` resource named `message`.

To use an `id` that exists in the Android framework, you can see here that you use `@android:id/progress`. And in source, you use it like you had it: `android.R.id.progress`.

Otherwise, use `android:id="@=id/myIdentifier"` in XML and
`findViewById(R.id.myIdentifier)` in code.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html

Comment: Thank you. I did not create any layout myself.I tried to use Android default `ProgressDialog`.Also when I try `R.id.body` instead of `android.R.id.progress`,error removes but in run time,body returns **null**.